# How to pull value from hidden input field

Tags: c#

I have the following code that does a POST to a website:

```
private static void Submit()
    {

        string formUrl = "mywebsite";

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
        req.CookieContainer = _cookieContainer;
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.Method = "POST";

        string token = string.Empty;

        string formParams =
            string.Format("formParams");
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        }
        WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
    }
```

What returns on the response is this:

```
<input type='hidden' name ='FW_REQUEST_ID_TOKEN' value =  '1446493462417_59.16698819328226' />
```

What I need to do is extract the value of that hidden input, in other words the "1446493...." so that I can use that information to make another POST.  How can I extract it?

Comment: What you're looking for is called a "DOM Parser".  The HTML Agility Pack is a common example of one.

Comment: Can you give the hidden input an id? If so you can do something like this: document.getElementById("#FW_REQUEST_ID_TOKEN").value;

Comment: @Tarzan, that should work in a Javascript running inside a browser.
it seems tha OP need to handle the response as a string within c# code. I think David has the right approach

Comment: As david said. Using HtmlAgilityPack would be one way to achieve that. Loading the response in HTML document using the LoadHtml method. Then you can find all <p> tags for example. Something like doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("p")

Comment: If you are using C# then I assume you are using ASP.net. If that is the case, then you can handle a hidden input just like any other input when extracting the value.

Comment: Do you want to extract the value on the client side or server side? Are you using webforms or MVC?

Answer (score 1):

If you would consider using a DOM Parser. You can install HTML Agility Pack from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack)

Once installed you can load the response in the HTML Document.

```
string htmlResult = client.UploadString("URL", "POST", "data to post");
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlResult);
```

Find your input by Id after getting all inputs.

```
var inputTags = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("input").ToList();
```